# Use CSS filters in svg image tag?

Tags: reactjs, svg

When using basic CSS filters, I can do something like:

```
<img src="..." style={{ filter: "blur(5px) ..." }} />
```

Or:

```
<img src="..." style="filter: blur(5px)" />
```

This will work fine. I wish to do this within an SVG `<image>` tag. I am not sure why the same inline styling never gets applied. There is a filter attribute within the image tag but I believe it only accepts tags like `<feGaussianBlur>` and other 'primative' filter tags. They do not have the functionality of what I need, ex: grayscale, huechange etc.

How do I make use CSS filters in an `<image>`?

The specific example is in React.

Comment: Was typing in a rush, thanks!

Comment: Your example should work in Firefox.

Comment: CSS Filters are a subset of SVG Filters - all of CSS filter capabilities are doable in a SVG Filter & they also provide much more capability beyond that. Good place to start: https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-filters/

Comment: Although the example may work, that is not the question. The question is how I can use CSS filter attributes inside a `<image>` instead of `<img>`. If you create a `<svg>` and add an `<image>` and style it similar to the example, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The folowing SVG filter is almost the same as the CSS **blur(5px)** - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#filter_functions)

```
<filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
</filter>
```

```html
 <svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
   <filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
       <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3.5"></feGaussianBlur>
   </filter>
   <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
          filter="url(#svgBlur)" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

### grayscale()

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
         style="filter: grayscale(0.5);" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

#### sepia()

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
         style="filter: sepia(80%);" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

#### hue-rotate();

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
         style="filter:hue-rotate(0.1turn);" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

#### brightness()

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
         style="filter: brightness(50%);" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

#### saturate()

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
         style="filter: saturate(200)" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

#### invert()

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <image xlink:href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" 
         style="filter: invert(100%);" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

---

You can also use HTML **<img>** in a SVG **<foreignObject>**

> The  SVG element includes elements from a different XML
> namespace. In the context of a browser, it is most likely (X)HTML. - [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

```html
<svg id="img3" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 212 161">
    <foreignObject  x="0" y="0" width="212" height="160">
        <img src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png"
             width="212" height="160"
             style="filter: brightness(20%);" />
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that feGaussianBlur is very similar to a blur(x). This is not what I was asking about though. I was asking about the other CSS filter attributes that are not in the 'fe...' tags. For example, huechange, invert, sapia, saturate.

Comment: @useruseruseruseruser It does support those effects that have mentioned.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The question was asking for an equivalent. For example, instead of using huerotate, saturate, brightness etc to taint an image a certain color, I am asking how would I be able to use the same functionalities in an `<image>`. However, I did completely forget about foreignObject so I'll give +1. I may be misremembering, but I believe it to be slightly unsafe somehow.